# MapLibre order fill-layer feature collection render position/z-index

Tags: turfjs, maplibre-gl

In my maplibre app I render a feature-collection of polygons and display popups when a specific feature is hovered. As some polygons may overlap others I want to order them based on their size.

[image: Maplibre feature-collection layer]

Only thing I've found is the `layout` property [`fill-sort-key`](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-style-spec/layers#layout-fill-fill-sort-key) that I'll assign during layer creation. Although this does not seem to have any effect.

> Sorts features in ascending order based on this value. Features with a higher sort key will appear above features with a lower sort key.

```js
layer.layout = { "fill-sort-key": ["get", "area"] };
```

Is this generally possible? Or do I have to draw a layer for each feature?

**TLDR**; How to order / set a z-index for features in a fill layer. (I want to order them by area size)